# Allow users to Use tags while adding content, not Adding new tags

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

At the moment, users can add their own tags while tagging their content. However, I want them to only be able to **use existing tags**, not **add new tags**. Just like this website has when you ask a new question and add tags, you can't add your own (except for those with permission).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used a module called [Taxonomy Access Control](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) to add "Add Tag" permissions for each tag I wanted them to be able to use and removed it on the default tag (the ones not existing).